# Oracle apex checkbox event

Tags: checkbox, event-handling, oracle-apex

I am using a text field and a button in my apex application with a click event (dynamic action) for the button. After the button was pressed, data from a SQL will be inserted into the text field with this PL/SQL code:

```
declare
l_result varchar2(32700);
begin
     for c1 in(
     select ename
     from emp
     ) loop
     l_result := l_result || c1.ename || chr(10);
    end loop;
   :Px_TEXTAREA_ITEM := l_result;
 end;
```

This works but now I would like to exchange the button event with a checkbox event. How to add if...else statement inside the PL/SQL query, which inserts the data if the checkbox is checked and empty the text field if it's unchecked?

Comment: you can use true and false actions of the dynamic action itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is sample on how to use a DA with a checkbox. This is on version 21.1 but the mechanism works for any version.
Functionality: if checkbox checked then employee SCOTT gets a salary raise of 1, if checkbox unchecked then employee SCOTT gets a salary decrease of 1. This is on EMP/DEMP sample data.

1. Create a page item `P37_TOGGLE_SCOTT` of type "Checkbox". Checked value "Y", unchecked value "N"
2. Create a dynamic action on change of page item `P37_TOGGLE_SCOTT` named "Raise/Lower Scott Salary". Client condition: "Item = Value", Item: P37_TOGGLE_SCOTT, Value: Y
3. Create a true action Execute Server-side Code with pl/sql code:

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE emp SET sal = sal + 1 WHERE ename = 'SCOTT';
END;
```

4. Create a false action Execute Server-side Code with pl/sql code:

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE emp SET sal = sal - 1 WHERE ename = 'SCOTT';
END;
```

It should be clear how to use the above sample for your business case.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)